# CSS no carga correctamente cuando lo subo a mi hosting

Tags: html, css, clase

Tengo un problema que me esta matando. Trabajando con Brackets puedo ver mi página realizada correctamente en mi servidor local, pero cuando la subo a mi servidor de hosting no se visualiza de manera correcta.

El problema surge en el div con clase ".texto-fijo"

Asi se ve en mi servidor local:

[image: Servidor local]

Así se ve en mi servidor de hosting:

[image: Servidor de hosting]

De hecho en mi archivo local se ve bien en modo responsive, pero en el servidor esta todo mal.

Pueden encontrar el error en [www.centrodentalcofico.com.ar](http://centrodentalcofico.com.ar)

Gracias por la ayuda.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/favicon-CDC.png">

<title>Centro Dental Cofico</title>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mogra" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- CSS -->
<link href="assets/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/node_modules/bootstrap-touch-slider/bootstrap-touch-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/core.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">    

<div class="container">
    <section id="header">
       <div class="texto-fijo wow fadeInUp anidur-1s">
           <div class="texto-interno">
               <h2>DESDE 1996</h2>
               <h1>ESTÉTICA SALUD ARMONÍA</h1>
           </div>
       </div>
        <div class="slider-principal">
            <div>
                <img src="images/header/1-final.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/header/2-final.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/header/3-final.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/header/4-final.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/header/5-final.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/header/6-final.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/header/7-final.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/header/8-final.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/header/9-final.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="images/header/10-final.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

El CSS de esa seccion es:

```
.texto-fijo{
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 50;
   bottom: 10px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
.texto-fijo .texto-interno{
   width: 500px;
   height: 60px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: rgba( 71, 71, 71, 0.456 );
   border-radius: 12px
}
.texto-fijo h2{
   font-size: 18px;
   color: #FFF
}
.texto-fijo h1{
   font-size: 25px;
   margin-top: -20px;
   color: #FFF
}
```

Comment: Hola Pablo bienvenido al sitio!, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!, sería importante agregar el código relevante.

Comment: ¿El margin top es el mismo en ambos casos?

Comment: Si, en ambas imagenes tienen el mismo codigo, solo que en la nube no se visualiza de igual manera que en mi servidor local.

Comment: @Pablo Colqui podrias agregar el html para ayudarte

Comment: Ahi agregue parte del codigo en cuestion

Comment: Revisa como acomodas las hojas de estilo, y cuales tienen prioridad. Esto porque el navegador interpreta linea por linea, es decir, si tienes una clase que se llame "miClase" en un archivo css colocado en primer lugar (Digamos que es jquery.css) y en tu hoja de estilos del sitio, tienes una clase que se llame de la misma manera "miClase" le hará caso a la primer clase que encuentre. (Podría ser una solución), en tu caso parece ser que **bootstrap te esta jugando una mala pasada!**

Comment: Puede sonar muy tonto pero a mí me ha pasado más de una vez... ¿Has probado a borrar la caché cuando visualizas la página desde tu servidor?

Comment: La solucion fue por parte de @Cig, el problema era el orden en que ponia el CSS. Muchas gracias! Estoy llorando jajaja

Answer (score 1):

La solucion la proporciono Cig, el problema era el orden en que ingresaba las CSS, pero puse como primera opcion mis CSS y luego las de Bootstrap. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No sé porqué te ocurre en un sitio si y en otro no, supongo que usarás distintos navegadores y diferentes configuraciones y "resoluciones" y es que el problema es un margin-top que hay por ahí cuando se aplica una cierta regla. En mi caso, que lo veo mal, se soluciona poniendo un margin-top a 0:

```
.texto-fijo h1 {
    margin-top: 0px
}
```

Y con esto lo veo bien, es decir, en el fichero css/responsive.css (http://centrodentalcofico.com.ar/css/responsive.css) en la línea 66, hay una regla que aplica esto a la clase .texto-fiho en el elemento h1:

```
.texto-fijo h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Supongo que en tu casa tendrás una resolución distinta y por eso no lo ves mal, pero en el trabajo tendrán una que se aplique por la regla en dicho fichero y verán por tanto, mal.

Answer (score 0):

La razón de porqué te sucede es muy probablemente culpa de boostrap, ya que directamente este esta afectando los `margin` de `h1` y `h2`, y tampoco **tienes estilos que afecten a estos dos directamente** y que sobreescriban los estilos por defecto del framework.

**Puedes corregir los margin de cada uno**, colocandoles una clase a cada elemento y luego corregirla en tu css. Cambiando el margin por defecto en cada uno.

Ahora, también puedes arreglarlo, **asignando al padre un interlineado específico y común para estos dos hijos**, solo debes agregar algo como esto en tu hoja de estilos:

```
.texto-fijo .texto-interno h1,
.texto-fijo .texto-interno h2 {
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

Por cierto, una recomendación: No coloques tantos archivos css por separado, siendo como veo, varios puedes combinarlos en uno solo, por ejemplo: `style.css, demo.css, core.css o responsive.css` podrían perfectamente ser uno solo. Lo mejor es aliviar un poco la sobrecarga de archivos al servidor.

Avisanos como te fue. Éxitos!